# How to separate front end and back end when developing a multi page site

Tags: django, frontend

I have a project, making a website as a company home page. As you know, these kind site need SEO, so we cannot use SPA, which is easier to separate with back-end.

We use Django as the back-end. In previous multi-page project, we always wrote Django template. As you know, it's so terrible to do this, writing front code in python project.

We want to do something else this time, So is there any sample, showing how to separate front end and back end when developing a multi page site?

1. multi-page, so router is made in back end
2. multi-page, so the page is rendered in back end.

It seems not easy...... :(

Comment: I'd recommend looking at what you get after completing the Django tutorials, as they are also there to teach the best practices in terms of separating models from view logic from templates.

Comment: @raphv， I make it after a period study,  have post a starter project on github, you can check the code, the readme is in Chinese, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I make a structure myself

https://github.com/njleonzhang/webpack-django-starter

Readme is in Chinese, sorry for that.

Comment: Amazing job, this is the only solution to this that I can found online.

Comment: @user3667089, Thank you, sorry for the non-English readme. :)